# Changing an NSObject inside of a NSMutableArray from a Singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a singleton which looks like this:

```
@implementation BARTicketManager

+ (BARTicketManager *)sharedManager {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static BARTicketManager *shared = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[BARTicketManager alloc] initUniqueInstance];
    });
    return shared;
}

- (id) initUniqueInstance {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        /* holds the list of TicketPurchase objects */
        _ticket_list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The _ticket_list above is declared as:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *ticket_list;
```

This list holds objects of type TicketPurchase. A method inside of TicketPurchase is 'setTicketAsReserved' as follows:

```
- (void) setTicketAsReserved:(NSDate *)reserved_datetime {

    _status = RESERVED;
    _reserved_datetime = reserved_datetime;

}
```

The problem I am having, is that when I run through the objects in the _ticket_list and call 'setTicketAsReserved' on some of those objects, and then attempt to access them by calling the singleton again, the value for _reserved_datetime is not saved, whereas the value of _status IS saved.

Can anyone understand why this would be the case?

**Edit:**

Relevant declarations for TicketPurchase:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSDate *reserved_datetime;
@property (nonatomic) TicketStatus status;
```

Comment: Show us your declarations.  I'm guessing that _reserved_datetime is not `strong`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `reserved_datetime` property is declared `weak`, it's likely getting deallocated.  Try changing that declaration to `strong`, since you want the `TicketPurchase` class to keep the `reserved_datetime` property around.

Comment: yup, and if the app uses arc, ticket list should be declared strong.